# Difference between Display.getCurrent.close() and PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close()

Tags: eclipse-plugin

What is the difference between Display.getCurrent.close();  and PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close(); ?

Answer (score 0):

`Display.getCurrent.close()` closes the current display (there is normal only one display). You would never uses this in a Eclipse plug-in as it will crash Eclipse. The only place it is normally used is in a RCP class implementing `IApplication`.

`PlatformUI.getWorkbench().close()` closes the Eclipse workbench and all its windows. You would uses this to shutdown Eclipse cleanly.